# CLion compilation error with Qt6Widgets.dll (Qt6Widgets.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)

Tags: windows, qt, clion

The error
`(Qt6Widgets.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)`
seems to appear when I manually try to compile the .exe in the cmakebuild directory.

When I try to compile in Clion I get this error:

```
Process finished with exit code -1073741515 
(0xC0000135)
```

I check the installation folder for Qt and the Qt6Widgets.dll exists.

I also try to compile in another computer and it works, I also install all the applications that i needed Qt and Clion and that doesn't change anything. (I'm on Windows 10)

Comment: ***I check the installation folder for Qt and the Qt6Widgets.dll exists*** I bet that is not the same folder as your executable and you have not modified your PATH environment variable to add that folder to the list of paths windows searches to find dlls. This document describes where your OS will look to find the required dlls: [https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order#standard-search-order-for-desktop-applications](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order#standard-search-order-for-desktop-applications)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just entirely reload the project and copy paste everything in the new project and it worked.
I had to choose the Console compilation when creating the project, i don't know if there were other options.